# Android SQLite taking a long time to complete

Tags: android, sql, performance

I am working on building an android app but I'm nothing that my SQL operations are taking forever to complete

I have profiled the app to narrow it down to the act of moving the Cursor to the first row of the result set for a simple select query (only returning 1 row where I'm testing it to eliminate the size of the result set as a problem.

Are there any better options for moving to the start of the result set?

edit:

some code:

```
public Cursor sqlQuery(String Sql)
{
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery(Sql, null);
    //start at the first spot
    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

and the calling code

```
    Cursor Slots = evedb.sqlQuery("SELECT attrib.value, "
            +"attribtypes.attributename "
            +"FROM dgmTypeAttribs AS attrib "
            +"INNER JOIN invTypes AS type "
            +"ON attrib.typeID = type._ID "
            +"INNER JOIN dgmAttribs AS attribtypes "
            +"ON attrib.attributeID = attribtypes._ID "
            +"AND attribtypes.attributename = 'hiSlots'  "
            +"AND type.typeName = '" + shipname + "'");
```

this runs 3 times and i have time it to approximately 2 secs for all the rest of the code or over a minute with this in.

i have also run just the rawQuery statement with out the move to first and its takes bout 18 secs so im looking at the worst part of the code first.

Comment: Could you please share us the code you have, and see if you are doing something wrong. Did you tried running in sqlite console on the adb the queries?

Comment: see my comment below i have tried a number of options for moving the pointer but that particular operation on  newly created cursor is blowing out my load times from about 2 secs for the 3 query's to over a minute.

Comment: code added with more details on tests already done to find the source of my issues.

Comment: OK I have checked the code. The moveToFirst should not take so long. Are you trying this at debug on runtime? And you are trying in emulator or on a live phone?

Comment: I have been working in the emulator so far to make it easier (my hone doesn't like connecting to my pc, i have just checked it on my phone and its much faster (about 10 secs) but still a little slow for my liking when I know there is a major bottle neck there I would like to clear up if I can as other intents have dozens of queries that are needed for them.

Comment: Try a simpler query and see if that works fine. Something like this: `SELECT 1,2,3,4,5;` How is this working?

Comment: @Philderbeast i have same problem now , did you got any solution related this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably, have large datasets. What you can do:

1. Ensure you have proper indexes (all your FK fields are indexed? have you set PK on your _ID fields for every table?) EVERY field used in ON, or WHERE syntax should be indexed (generally speaking).
2. You should change a bit your query:

   ```
   +"ON attrib.attributeID = attribtypes._ID "
   +"WHERE attribtypes.attributename = 'hiSlots'  "
   +"AND type.typeName = '" + shipname + "'");
   ```
3. Consider using PreparedStatement
4. Check amount of data used by this query - remove where condition and just put count(*)
5. Consider to split one big query into few smaller. There is also EXPLAIN command which can be used to check way used by SQLite to retrieve data. Look [here](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) to get more information.

Moving to first row is the point when query is starting to collect data so this is just database performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the snipet of code you are currently using to see what is possibly going wrong?

If you are talking about moving to a first item in a cursor I use: `c.moveToFirst()` where `c` is the cursor.

Comment: i have tried moveToFrist() moveToNext() and moveToPosition(0) but all result in the activity taking over 1 minute to initialize for just 3 queries